# Large Data import with PHP, MySQL and XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am building a script that imports the data from an uploaded XML file into MySQL, but not directly. The function itself has only one query, but it always times out. That query has to join two tables to find a single ID that would be inserted with the XML data in a third table.

Here is the function that does it:

```
public function imprtTVLApi($file) {
    global $db, $user;
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $message = '';
    $text = '';
    $streaming_websites = array(
        'megavideo.com' => '1',
        'vidxden' => '2',
        'videobb.com' => '4',
        'veevr.com' => '5',
        'vureel.com' => '6',
        '2gb-hosting.com' => '7',
        'videoweed.com' => '9',
        'divxhosting.net' => '11',
        'movshare.net' => '12',
        'novamov.com' => '13',
        'ovfile.com' => '14',
        'videozer.com' => '15',
        'putlocker.com' => '16',
        'sockshare.com' => '17',
        'videoweed.es' => '18',
        'uploadc.com' => '19',
        'wupload.com' => '20',
        'vidbux.com' => '21',
        'veoh.com' => '22',
        'mixturevideo.com' => '23',
        'youtube.com' => '24',
        'filebox.com' => '25',
        'filenuke.com' => '26',
        'hostingbulk.com' => '27',
        'zalaa.com' => '28',
        'nowvideo.eu' => '29',
        'vidhog.com' => '30',
        'bitshare.com' => '31',
        'muchshare.net' => '32',
        'allmyvideos.net' => '33',
        'gorillavid.in' => '34',
        'daclips.in' => '35',
        'movpod.in' => '36',
        'stream2k.eu' => '37'
    );
    if ( $ext == "xml") :
        $tv  = new DomDocument();
        $tv->recover = TRUE;
        $tv->load($file) or die("Could not load the file! " .$file);
        $tvSearch = $tv->getElementsByTagName( "url" );
        $count = 0;

        foreach( $tvSearch as $tv ) {   

            // name
            $names = $tv->getElementsByTagName('name');
            $name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;

            // seasons
            $seasons = $tv->getElementsByTagName('season');
            $season = $seasons->item(0)->nodeValue;

            // episode
            $episodes = $tv->getElementsByTagName('episode');
            $episode = $episodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

            // episode
            $links = $tv->getElementsByTagName('loc');
            $link = $links->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $user = $user->uid;
            $url  = $db->escape($link);
            $stream1 = $this->getHostFromURL($url);
            $stream = $streaming_websites[$stream1];
            $added = time();
            $status = "ok";
            $sql = 'SELECT e.id AS epid FROM ' .$this->epTable. ' AS e INNER JOIN ' .$this->tvTable. ' AS t ON e.show_ID = t.id WHERE t.title = "' .$name. '" AND e.season = "' .$season. '" AND e.episode = "' .$episode. '" LIMIT 1';
            $row = $db->first($sql);

            if( isset($row['epid'])) {

                $data = array(
                    'user_ID' => $user,
                    'url' => sanitize($url),
                    'stream_ID' => $stream,
                    'e_ID' => intval($row['epid']),
                    'added' => intval($added),
                    'status' => $status
                );


                $text .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO " .$this->lkTable. " (`user_ID`, `url`, `stream_ID`, `e_ID`, `added`, `status`) VALUES ('" .$data['user_ID']. "', '" .$data['url']. "', '" .$data['stream_ID']. "', '" .$data['e_ID']. "', '" .$data['added']. "', '" .$data['status']. "')";

            } else {
                $message = "Show not found";
            }
            $count++;

        }
        $myFile =  "export_" .$user->uid. "_" .time(). ".sql";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData = $text;
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
        parse_mysql_dump($myFile);
        unlink($myFile);
        $message = "Links: " .$count. ", Your links were added and they will show up on the site in a minute!";
    else :
        $message = "Incorrect file format! Must be XML!";
    endif;
    print($message);
}
```

And here is the database structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `episodes2`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `episodes2` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Untitled',
  `show_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `episode` bigint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `season` bigint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tvragepage` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `airdate` int(15) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `added` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2000117 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tvshows2`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tvshows2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imdbid` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `tvrageid` varchar(125) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `poster` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `slider` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `tagline` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `plot` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `released` varchar(18) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `channel` smallint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `runtime` char(6) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `storyline` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `genres` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `actors` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `votes` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `oscars` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `seasons` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `mpaa` enum('TV-14','TV-Y','TV-PG','TV-MA') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TV-14',
  `trivia` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('never_aired','cancelled_ended','returning_series','new_series','on_hiatus','tbd','pilot_rejected','in_development','pilot_ordered') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'returning_series',
  `permalink` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `classification` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unavailable',
  `airtime` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unavailable',
  `airday` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Monday',
  `ended` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `permalink` (`permalink`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=31994 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tv_links`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tv_links` (
  `link_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url` varchar(225) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `stream_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `e_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `added` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('ok','broken','deleted','pending') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ok',
  PRIMARY KEY (`link_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
  KEY `e_ID` (`e_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The data is sent to MySQL after a .sql file is created by the loop.
The key here is to find the episode id that would be imported in the links table.

Do you have any suggestions on how to make it faster or any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code relevant to the question, in the question body. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. if pastebin ever goes down, your question is useless.

Comment: You want to make it faster. Ok. But which parts are slow? Have you ever profile your script? Take a look at [Xdebug profiling](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

Comment: I am trying to make it work. Currently, it only times out. But I'll take a look.